# How to call ajax from grid view and redirect in same page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default4.aspx.cs/SaveUser",
    data: "{ 'taskid': '" + taskid + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var flag = data;
        if (flag == "fail") {
            alert("task in use");
        }
        else {
            alert("task not in use");
        }
    }
});
```

I have function in called `SaveUser` like this:

```
public void SaveUser()
{
    //something to do;
}
```

In `Default4.aspx.cs` when I call this it's not executing. I tried, and it is calling the javascript because I gave alert there, but it's not entering AJAX. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be `static` and decorated with `[WebMethod]` attribute. Also a parameter named `taskid` should be passed to this method.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void SaveUser(int taskid)
{
    //something to do;
}
```

You don't need to give the path with `.cs` extension. Remove `.cs` from `url` part of `ajax`

```
url: "Default4.aspx/SaveUser",
```

Comment: yes i have done it ...but its not entering in ajax code!!!! any pre setting for ajax

Comment: remove `.cs` from url

Comment: {"files":["~\/Default4.aspx"],"map":[["html",[[0,119,2662,43]]],["head",
,["input#Button1",[[0,1341,93]]],["table#GridView1",[[0,1481,1251],:481,1251]],[[0,1481,1251]],
,1251]]]]}]],["td",[[0,1481,1251]]]]}]],["input#GridView1_btnOther_1", giving errror like this when i inspect

Answer (score 0):

If asp.net web from with RouteConfig.cs file  in **App_Start**

Please correct in RegisterRoute

```
//Rest of code is ommited
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

and ajax call will be

```
var obj={};
obj.taskid=taskid ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default4.aspx/SaveUser",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var flag = data.d; //Add .d here
        if (flag == "fail") {
            alert("task in use");
        }
        else {
            alert("task not in use");
        }
    }
});
```

and web method in `Default4.aspx`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static   String SaveUser(String taskid)
{
  return "OK";
}
```